# Python: order of elements is wrong for dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I've the following code:

```
tweet = {"user" : "joelgrus", "text" : "Data Science is Awesome", "retweet_count" : 100}

print "tweet:", tweet
```

The output after running the script is:

```
tweet: {'text': 'Data Science is Awesome', 'retweet_count': 100, 'user': 'joelgrus'}
```

Why is the order of the elements (seemingly) wrong? I thought the output should just be:

```
tweet: {'user': 'joelgrus', 'text': 'Data Science is Awesome', 'retweet_count': 100}
```

Comment: Dictionaries are inherently unordered

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary).

Comment: I recommend Googling your planned question title before posting it, as that may sometimes provide an immediate answer to your question.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yeah you're right, I'm sorry for asking this question, I just assumed that dictionaries are ordered (since that seems to such a logic thing). I would delete the question, but I believe that's frowned upon as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries do not keep their lists in order: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

Theres a note on the page that explains:

> CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an
>   arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python
>   implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions
>   and deletions.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this answer once I'm allowed to in 12 min